# Не изменяется задний фон QComboBox

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qss, qcombobox

В чем проблема? В *Qt Designer* задний фон `QComboBox` белый, а в самом коде после запуска через командную строку нет.

Что можно сделать?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(433, 454)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(433, 454))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(433, 454))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.011, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(182, 29, 212, 255), stop:1 rgba(48, 7, 182, 255));\n"
"")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 231, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 110, 91, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(61, 135, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(76, 100, 255);\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 271, 40))
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(94, 94, 94))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Highlight, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0, 128))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.NoBrush)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.PlaceholderText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(94, 94, 94))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Highlight, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0, 128))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.NoBrush)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.PlaceholderText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(94, 94, 94))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Highlight, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0, 128))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.NoBrush)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.PlaceholderText, brush)
        self.comboBox_2.setPalette(palette)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.comboBox_2.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.comboBox_2.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.comboBox_2.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.comboBox_2.setEditable(False)
        self.comboBox_2.setMaxVisibleItems(5)
        self.comboBox_2.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(45, 45))
        self.comboBox_2.setFrame(False)
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.comboBox_2.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Example"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выберите"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выполнить"))
        self.comboBox_2.setCurrentText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(5, _translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(6, _translate("MainWindow", "7"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(7, _translate("MainWindow", "8"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(8, _translate("MainWindow", "9"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(9, _translate("MainWindow", "10"))

class ExmApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)

StyleSheet = '''

QScrollBar:vertical
 {
     background-color: white;
     width: 7px;
     margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
     border: 0px transparent;
     border-radius: 0px;
 }

 QScrollBar::handle:vertical
 {
     background-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);         
     min-height: 10px;
     border-radius: 3px;
 }

 QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical
 {
     margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
     border-image: url(./images/up_arrow_disabled.png);        
     height: 10px;
     width: 10px;
     subcontrol-position: top;
     subcontrol-origin: margin;
 }

 QScrollBar::add-line:vertical
 {
     margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
     border-image: url(./images/down_arrow_disabled.png);       
     height: 10px;
     width: 10px;
     subcontrol-position: bottom;
     subcontrol-origin: margin;
 }

 QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:hover,QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:on
 {

     border-image: url(./images/up_arrow.png);                 
     height: 10px;
     width: 10px;
     subcontrol-position: top;
     subcontrol-origin: margin;
 }


 QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:hover, QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:on
 {
     border-image: url(./images/down_arrow.png);                
     height: 10px;
     width: 10px;
     subcontrol-position: bottom;
     subcontrol-origin: margin;
 }

 QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical
 {
     background: none;
 }


 QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical
 {
     background: none;
 }

QComboBox {
    font: 12pt Arial;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5%;
    max-height: 30px;
    min-width: 140px;
    color: black;
    selection-background-color: #5e5e5e;
    border-radius: 7px;                 /* закруглёные углы */
 }
QComboBox::hover {
    background-color: rgba(202, 202, 202, 240);

 }
QComboBox:on { /* сдвиньте текст, когда всплывающее окно откроется */
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-left: 4px;
 }
QComboBox::drop-down {
    subcontrol-origin: padding;
    subcontrol-position: top right;
    width: 40px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-left-color: darkgray;
    border-left-style: solid;          
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;      
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
 }

QComboBox::down-arrow {
    image: url(E:/nvuti/pngs/1.png);            /* <<=====< */
 }
QComboBox::down-arrow:on { 
    top: 1px;
    left: 1px;
    image: url(E:/nvuti/pngs/2.png);              /* <<=====< */
 }

QListView {
    font: 12pt Arial;
    background-color: white;
    outline: 0;
    color: black;
    selection-background-color: rgba(202, 202, 202, 240);
 }
QListView::item {
    min-height: 20px;
    padding: 5%;
 }
QLabel {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: 15pt Arial;
 }
'''



if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)         

    window = ExmApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По моему умозаключению правильнее и понятнее описывать таблицу стилей в одном месте.
Я обычно это делаю здесь `app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)`

Я перенес `MainWindow.setStyleSheet`  в `StyleSheet`

Я не совсем понял для чего вам  `palette` , поэтому убрал на всякий случай.

Вот что получается:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(433, 454)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(433, 454))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(433, 454))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)

# --- vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
#        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.011, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(182, 29, 212, 255), stop:1 rgba(48, 7, 182, 255));\n"
#"")
# --- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 231, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 110, 91, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"background-color: rgb(61, 135, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(76, 100, 255);\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 271, 40))
        '''
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()              # ???????????????????????????????
        ...
        '''
#        self.comboBox_2.setPalette(palette)    # ???????????????????????????????

        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.comboBox_2.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.comboBox_2.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.comboBox_2.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.comboBox_2.setEditable(False)
        self.comboBox_2.setMaxVisibleItems(5)
        self.comboBox_2.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(45, 45))
        self.comboBox_2.setFrame(False)
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.comboBox_2.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Example"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выберите"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выполнить"))
        self.comboBox_2.setCurrentText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(5, _translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(6, _translate("MainWindow", "7"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(7, _translate("MainWindow", "8"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(8, _translate("MainWindow", "9"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(9, _translate("MainWindow", "10"))

class ExmApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)



StyleSheet = '''
/* --- QMainWindow --------------------------------------- */
QMainWindow {
    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.011, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(182, 29, 212, 255), stop:1 rgba(48, 7, 182, 255));
}

/* --- QScrollBar --------------------------------------- */
QScrollBar:vertical {
    background-color: white;
    width: 7px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 0px transparent;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
    background-color: rgb(175, 175, 175);         
    min-height: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
    margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
    border-image: url(./images/up_arrow_disabled.png);        
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
    margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
    border-image: url(./images/down_arrow_disabled.png);       
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:hover,QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:on {
    border-image: url(./images/up_arrow.png);                 
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:hover, QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:on {
    border-image: url(./images/down_arrow.png);                
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical {
    background: none;
}
QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical {
    background: none;
}

/* --- QComboBox --------------------------------------- */
QComboBox {
    font: 12pt Arial;
    background-color: white;                  
    padding: 5%;
    max-height: 30px;
    min-width: 140px;
    color: black;
    selection-background-color: #5e5e5e;
    border-radius: 7px;      /* закруглёные углы */
}
QComboBox::hover {
    background-color: rgba(202, 202, 202, 240);  
}
QComboBox:on { /* сдвиньте текст, когда всплывающее окно откроется */
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-left: 4px;
}
QComboBox::drop-down {
    subcontrol-origin: padding;
    subcontrol-position: top right;
    width: 40px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-left-color: darkgray;
    border-left-style: solid;          
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;      
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

QComboBox::down-arrow {
    image: url(E:/nvuti/pngs/1.png);        
}
QComboBox::down-arrow:on { 
    top: 1px;
    left: 1px;
    image: url(E:/nvuti/pngs/2.png);            
}

/* --- QListView --------------------------------------- */
QListView {
    font: 12pt Arial;
    background-color: white;
    outline: 0;
    color: black;
    selection-background-color: rgba(202, 202, 202, 240);
}
QListView::item {
    min-height: 20px;
    padding: 5%;
}

/* --- QLabel --------------------------------------- */
QLabel {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: 15pt Arial;
}
'''


if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)         

    window = ExmApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прямо то что нужно!

Answer (score 1):

Я решил свою проблему так, что сделал фон главного окна белым, а поверх кнопок добавил label с градиентом, а поверх него кнопка и Combobox. Это помогло

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы делаете проект через QtDesigner, то никак - придётся менять параметр вручную после каждой компиляции

Comment: проблема в том, что я уже изменил все возможное

Comment: А в приложении какой цвет?

Comment: градиент, от розового к фиолетовому, и он почему-то передается на combobox, хотя в stylesheet указано что background-color: white;

Comment: Там вверху есть установка цвета на (94, 94, 94) и на (0, 0,128). Не уверен, но это тоже возможно может влиять

Comment: Может градиент от фона передаётся?

Comment: да, я про это и говорю. Но как это предотвратить - незнаю

Comment: есть идея, попробую шяс сделать. Сделать задний фон приложения белым, и накину поверх него label с градиентом

Comment: @КуатКурпенов   Никогда не говори никогда!